# Javascript SDK API Domains with custom protocols?

Tags: javascript, api, debugging, linkedin-api, custom-protocol

So I am writing an application in Node-Webkit/NW.js that needs a "Login to LinkedIn" button. We have to use a custom protocol/domain in order to allow hooking into the Dropbox API (let's call it app://example).

In the Application Details on the developer portal, for JavaScript API Domains I have "app://example" and "example." However, when I attempt to use my API key inside the application I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: JavaScript API Domain is restricted to example

Does LinkedIn not allow custom protocols, and only http/https? This is a big problem for us and I hope someone is able to answer.

Comment: I don't don't if "bump"s are a thing in StackOverflow...but getting an answer from someone who works at LinkedIn would be super helpful right now. Or a contact number to call them.

Answer (score 0):

Use a server in a controlled environment rather than the developer console to avoid this error.

Use a redirect from the `https://` protocol to the `app://` protocol in that controlled environment. Here is the process:

> Essentially, where I was previously seeing "Not allowed to load local resource: app://whatever/somefile.html", addOriginAccessWhitelistEntry eliminates the error and I see the appropriate app:// resource in the address bar with the following new error in the console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"
>
> That said, if I force a refresh at this point the resource rendering occurs as expected.

```
 nw.App.addOriginAccessWhitelistEntry('http://github.com/', 'app', 'myapp', true);
```

**References**

- [nw.js: app:// Protocol doesn't load for OAuth Redirect](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/1908)
- [nw.js: addOriginAccessWhitelistEntry](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/App#addoriginaccesswhitelistentrysourceorigin-destinationprotocol-destinationhost-allowdestinationsubdomains)